# Changing Request Path in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, url-routing, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

Prior to 3.0, I could change the path of a request (without any form of browser redirection) by just accessing the `HttpRequest` property of the `HttpContext` and then changed the value of the `Path`.

As an example, to display a page for a user who needed to change his/her password (irrespective of the page the user intended to visit), I extended the **HttpContext**

```
public static void ChangeDefaultPassword(this HttpContext context) 
=> context.Request.Path = "/Account/ChangePassword";
```

This piece of code takes the user to the action method `ChangePassword` in the `AccountController` *without executing* the action method the user intends to visit.

Then enters dotnet core 3.1.

In 3.1, the extension method changes the path. However, it never executes the action method. It **ignores** the updated path.

I am aware this is due to the changes in the routing.The endpoint can now be accessed with the extension method `HttpContext.GetEndpoint()`. There is also an extension method `HttpContext.SetEndpoint` which seems to be the right way to set a new endpoint. However, there is no sample of how to accomplish this.

**The Question**

How do I change the request path, without executing the original path?

**What I Have Tried**

1. I tried changing the path. It seems routing in dotnet core 3.1 ignores the value of the HttpRequest path value.
2. I tried redirecting with `context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ChangePassword");`. This worked but it *first* executed the original action method requested by the user. This behavior defeated the purpose.
3. I tried using the extension method `HttpContext.SetEndpoint`, but there was no example available to work with.

Comment: Are you modifying the URL in custom middleware? If yes, where in the pipeline does that middleware run?

Comment: I believe any change of URLs should go through the rewrite middleware, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @KirkLarkin I am not doing this in a middleware. I have a class which extended *CookieAuthenticationEvents*. I am doing this while validating the principal.

Comment: @LexLi This is not applicable

Comment: “not applicable” in which way?

Comment: @LexLi we are checking if the user, for example, has not been deactivated since his last login. Hence, we validate the principal against several criteria. Your suggested solution is not applicable because we need to dig up the detail of the logged in user and then ensure the user can perform the requested action. If not, we simply execute another action method that displays the appropriate message.

Comment: I think this "symptom" exists in middleware too. I've tried `httpContext.Request.Path` and `httpContext.Response.Redirect(httpContext.Request.Path)` and it seemingly just ignores it after changing the path. I've tried hardcoded paths and just about everything else I can think of. I was going to start my own SO question and found this one. My code basically follows the following article to the letter with a few fixes for Core 3.1 and a custom subscription check and redirect as mentioned: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx

Comment: @SumNone All middlewares called after the route middleware will have this "symptom". Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a working solution. My solution works by manually setting a new endpoint with the `SetEndpoint` extension method.

Here is an extension method I created to resolve this issue.

```cs
private static void RedirectToPath(this HttpContext context, string controllerName, string actionName )
{
    // Get the old endpoint to extract the RequestDelegate
    var currentEndpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

    // Get access to the action descriptor collection
    var actionDescriptorsProvider =
        context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();

    // Get the controller aqction with the action name and the controller name.
    // You should be redirecting to a GET action method anyways. Anyone can provide a better way of achieving this. 
    var controllerActionDescriptor = actionDescriptorsProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
        .Where(s => s is ControllerActionDescriptor bb
                    && bb.ActionName == actionName
                    && bb.ControllerName == controllerName
                    && (bb.ActionConstraints == null
                        || (bb.ActionConstraints != null
                            && bb.ActionConstraints.Any(x => x is HttpMethodActionConstraint cc
                            && cc.HttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethods.Get)))))
        .Select(s => s as ControllerActionDescriptor)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (controllerActionDescriptor is null) throw new Exception($"You were supposed to be redirected to {actionName} but the action descriptor could not be found.");

    // Create a new route endpoint
    // The route pattern is not needed but MUST be present. 
    var routeEndpoint = new RouteEndpoint(currentEndpoint.RequestDelegate, RoutePatternFactory.Parse(""), 1, new EndpointMetadataCollection(new object[] { controllerActionDescriptor }), controllerActionDescriptor.DisplayName);
    
    // set the new endpoint. You are assured that the previous endpoint will never execute.
    context.SetEndpoint(routeEndpoint);
}
```

**Important**

1. You must make the view of the action method available by placing it in the *Shared* folder. Alternatively, you may decide to provide a custom implementation of `IViewLocationExpander`
2. Before accessing the endpoint, the routing middleware must have executed.

**USAGE**

```
public static void ChangeDefaultPassword(this HttpContext context) 
=> context.RedirectToPath("Account","ChangePassword");
```

Comment: Is it not better to use the Use extension method for this?

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom You could just call `RedirectToPath` in a middleware or anywhere

Comment: Thats what I am doing in the code I did show below. Only it looks a bit different. Lets say more in line with what app.Use is supposed to do :-) If you look at my code I intercept the request before it goes further in the pipeline. If I did not implement this code and a "not found" page was generated the IIS server would present a "not found" page. By using this middleware I intercept that page and redirect to mine "not found" page.

Comment: @ShittuJosephOlugbenga, do you know how to set parameters in you example?

Answer (score 7):

The way I worked around this issue is to use `EndpointDataSource` directly, which is a singleton service that is available from DI as long as you have the routing services registered. It works as long as you can provide the controller name and the action name, which you can specify at compile time. This negates the need to use `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` or build the endpoint object or request delegate by yourself (which is pretty complicated...):

```
public static void RerouteToActionMethod(this HttpContext context, EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource, string controllerName, string actionName)
{
    var endpoint = endpointDataSource.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e =>
    {
        var descriptor = e.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
        // you can add more constraints if you wish, e.g. based on HTTP method, etc
        return descriptor != null
               && actionName.Equals(descriptor.ActionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               && controllerName.Equals(descriptor.ControllerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    });

    if (endpoint == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No valid endpoint found.");
    }

    context.SetEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: How do you use this? More specifically the endpointDataSource portion?

Comment: @SumNone EndpointDataSource is available via constructor DI as long as you called `services.AddRouting()` in `Startup`. I just pass it into this extension method

Comment: For my purposes this code was sufficient and to the point.
@SumNone usage will be `using (var scope = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.CreateScope()){ var eds = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EndpointDataSource>(); ctx.HttpContext.RerouteToActionMethod(eds, "MyController", "MyControllerMethod");}`

Comment: @scharnyw, do you know how to set parameters in you example?

Comment: This works for me compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Check your middleware order.

The middleware exposed by `.UseRouting()` is what's responsible for deciding which endpoint to hit based on the incoming request path.  If your path rewrite middleware comes later in the pipeline (like mine was), it'll be too late and the routing decision has been made.

Moving my custom middleware before `UseRouting()` ensured that the path was set as I needed it before the routing middleware had been hit.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfig)
{   
   //snip
   app.UseMiddleware<PathRewritingMiddleware>();
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
   });
   //snip       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar reroute issue. In my case, I want to reroute users to a "you don't have permissions" view when an AuthorationHandler fails. I applied the following code, notably (httpContext.Response.Redirect(...)) in (.Net Core 3.1) to route me to a NoPermissions action on a Home Controller.

In the handler class:

```
 protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, FooBarRequirement requirement) {
var hasAccess = await requirement.CheckAccess(context.User);
if (hasAccess)
context.Succeed(requirement);
else {
var message = "You do not have access to this Foobar function";
AuthorizeHandler.NoPermission(mHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext, context, requirement, message);
 }
}
```

I wrote a static class to handle the redirect, passing in the url expected by the controller and action plus an error message, and the redirect permanent flag set to true:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Foo.BusinessLogic.Security {
public static class AuthorizeHandler {
    public static void NoPermission(HttpContext httpContext, 
AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IAuthorizationRequirement requirement, string 
errorMessage) {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        httpContext.Response.Redirect($"/home/nopermission/?m={errorMessage}", true);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the controller and action that handles the view and message

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult NoPermission(string m) {
 return View("NoPermission", m);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am manually selecting the matching endpoint in a DynamicRouteValueTransformer. I have a mostly working solution but have to switch to other priorities. Perhaps someone else can create a more elegant solution using built in Action executors.

```
RequestDelegate requestDelegate = async (HttpContext x) =>
{//manually handle controller activation, method invocation, and result processing
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(x, new RouteData(values), new ControllerActionDescriptor() { ControllerTypeInfo = controllerType.GetTypeInfo() });
    var activator = x.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IControllerActivator)) as ServiceBasedControllerActivator;
    var controller = activator.Create(new ControllerContext(actionContext));
    var arguments = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p =>
    {
        object r;
        if (requestData.TryGetValue(p.Name, out object value)) r = value;
        else if (p.ParameterType.IsValueType) r = Activator.CreateInstance(p.ParameterType);
        else r = null;
        return r;
    });
    var actionResultTask = methodInfo.Invoke(controller, arguments.ToArray());
    var actionTask = actionResultTask as Task<IActionResult>;
    if (actionTask != null)
    {
        var actionResult = await actionTask;
        await actionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);//errors here. actionContext is incomplete
    }
};

var endpoint = new Endpoint(requestDelegate, EndpointMetadataCollection.Empty, methodInfo.Name);
httpContext.SetEndpoint(endpoint);
```