# HttpContext GetEndpoint on modified request path .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, middleware, .net-5

I'm trying to create a middleware to handle country code in the url.
The code i have works great for removing the country code, so it's routed to the correct endpoint in the mvc pipeline.

The problem i have is that i need to do some actions depending on if the endpoint has a certain attribute or not.

I see that `HttpContext` has a method `GetEndpoint`, and this is exactly what i need.

When the countryCode is in the url (mysite.com/**us**/home/Index), the
`GetEndpoint` returns null.

But if i enter the site without the countryCode in the url (mysite.com/home/Index), then the `GetEndpoint` works.

How can i use the `GetEndpoint()` method on the modified request url?

Is it another property on `HttpContext` i need to change?

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    // mysite.com/us/home/Index
    var currentAddress = httpContext.Request.Path; 
    
    // mysite.com/home/Index
    httpContext.Request.Path = ExtractCountryCodeFromUrl(currentAddress); 

    var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint(); // null

    var hasMyAttribute = endPoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<MyAttribute>();
    // Do something...

    await next(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: How about using `Request.GetDisplayUrl();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this,

```cs
private static ControllerActionDescriptor GetControllerByUrl(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var pathElements = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Split("/").Where(m => m != "");
    string controllerName = (pathElements.ElementAtOrDefault(0) == "" ? null : pathElements.ElementAtOrDefault(0)) ?? "w";
    string actionName = (pathElements.ElementAtOrDefault(1) == "" ? null : pathElements.ElementAtOrDefault(1)) ?? "Index";

    var actionDescriptorsProvider = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();
    ControllerActionDescriptor controller = actionDescriptorsProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
    .Where(s => s is ControllerActionDescriptor bb
                && bb.ActionName == actionName
                && bb.ControllerName == controllerName
                && (bb.ActionConstraints == null
                    || (bb.ActionConstraints != null
                        && bb.ActionConstraints.Any(x => x is HttpMethodActionConstraint cc
                        && cc.HttpMethods.Any(m => m.ToLower() == httpContext.Request.Method.ToLower())))))
    .Select(s => s as ControllerActionDescriptor)
    .FirstOrDefault();
    return controller;
}
```

Then i can do this

```cs
ControllerActionDescriptor controller = GetControllerByUrl(httpContext);
var countryCodeAttribute = controller.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>();
```

I don't know how well this scales, but it will work for now.
I found the main part of the code here: [Changing Request Path in .Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065745/changing-request-path-in-net-core-3-1)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, the solution for the problem (at least mine) was the order of middlewares in the Startup: your custom middleware must be after the `UseRouting()`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```