# How to invoke controller and action using RequestDelegate in RouteEndpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I'm trying to generate a `List<Endpoint>` that will serve an `EndpointDataSource`. How can I invoke a controller and action using the `RequestDelegate`? I have tried to set the `RouteValues` but that does not work.

This is what I have tried.

```cs
var endpoints = new List<RouteEndpoint>();

endpoints.Add(new RouteEndpoint(
    requestDelegate: context => Task.CompletedTask,
    routePattern: RoutePatternFactory.Parse($"/blog"),
    order: 0,
    metadata: new EndpointMetadataCollection(new HttpMethodMetadata(new[] { "GET" }),
        new ControllerActionDescriptor() {
            RouteValues = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "controller", "Home" },
                { "action", "Index" }}
    ),
    displayName: "id"));

return endpoints;
```

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna a configuration to make your app can analyze the metadata and got the route value, then match the correct controller and action defined in route value? Thanks for your reply in advance sir.

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065745/changing-request-path-in-net-core-3-1).

Comment: @tiny-wa Not really, I want to create a custom EndpointDataSource where `/blog` routes to BlogController with the action Index.