# A dotnet core middleware for rewriting the request using HttpContext.SetEndpoint

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to rewrite the request path to an action method of a controller though a middleware and I think SetEnpoint function would help in doing that, but I can't find a proper example for it.

I tried to follow this thread: [Changing Request Path in .Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065745/changing-request-path-in-net-core-3-1) but it didnot work and the request path didnot change

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to rewrite the request, You just need to use [rewrite middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1), Why do you want to use `SetEnpoint `? Can you provide more details?